# AppCache doesent work with static files

Tags: html, tornado, html5-appcache, offline-caching

I try to make the application works offline, so only the json will be send to update the website, here is my appcache file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v = 0.1
/
NETWORK:
*
```

I get this reponse on the console:

```
[I 150323 19:22:38 web:1825] 200 GET /static/css/meteo.css?v=51211953b5b2ec0abdec17b4917b0ae6 (::1) 180.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:38 web:1825] 200 GET /static/css/semantic.min.css?v=b05c5612ace3ff40888d13bf56d56fa9 (::1) 37.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:38 web:1825] 200 GET /static/css/main.css?v=0e2d512c063c6b630de514cc664ce4e2 (::1) 2.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:38 web:1825] 200 GET /static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js?v=e40ec2161fe7993196f23c8a07346306 (::1) 8.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:38 web:1825] 200 GET /static/js/semantic.min.js?v=8c9818699a737630d5cbc6fcbaa1db8b (::1) 15.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:38 web:1825] 200 GET /static/js/geo.js?v=aefbcdb7b5c6ab60979ceb1ca264f09c (::1) 2.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:39 web:1825] 200 GET /static/fonts/icons.woff2 (::1) 2.00ms
[I 150323 19:22:39 web:1825] 304 GET /meteo.appcache (::1) 1.00ms
```

But it seems that it doesent work, here is how it is online:

[image]

And here is when i stop the server:

[image]

At [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), they say, that:

> Some browsers (e.g., Firefox) display a notification bar the first time a user loads an application that uses the application cache. The notification bar displays a message such as:
>
> This website (www.example.com) is asking to store data on your computer for offline use. [Allow] [Never for This Site] [Not Now]

But I dident got any message (firefox 36), and if I try to use `/*` in the manifest to ask him to cache everything, I got an error: `[W 150323 19:28:54 web:1825] 404 GET /* (::1) 3.00ms`,

And if I declare them explicitely, I dont get them!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that I dident understood what is `OFFLINE`, this is NO CONNECTION , and not server off!

[image]